# How do you superimpose two symbols over each other?

Tags: symbols, overlays

I want to superimpose two symbols, e.g. I want to superimpose `\vee` and `\wedge` and `>` and `<` symbols over each other (not above each other as in `stackrel`) and `Q` with a horizontal strike through like bar across it. I am using LyX 2.0.

Answer (score 37):

`\rlap` and `\llap` can be used to print a symbol without a width. Similar, the `mathtools package` provides commands `\mathrlap`, `\mathclap`, `\mathllap`. These commands offer a quick way for overlapping symbols.

Example, overlapping `\vee`, `\wedge` and Q like desired in your question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$\mathrlap{\vee}\wedge$
\rlap{Q}---
\end{document}
```

While `\rlap` produces a zero-width box where the content sticks out to the right, `\llap` does the same but to the left. `\mathclap` centers to the current position.

[image]

Answer (score 20):

You can define a generic `\superimpose` macro and then use it for various purposes. Add also the desired math atom class for the built symbol.

Note, however, that `\superimpose` only makes sense in the context of `\mathpalette`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\superimpose}[2]{{%
  \ooalign{%
    \hfil$\m@th#1\@firstoftwo#2$\hfil\cr
    \hfil$\m@th#1\@secondoftwo#2$\hfil\cr
  }%
}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\veewedge}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\superimpose{{\vee}{\wedge}}}}
\newcommand{\lessgreater}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\superimpose{{<}{>}}}}
\newcommand{\strikeQ}{\mathpalette\superimpose{{\textnormal{---}}{Q}}}

\newcommand{\dotineq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\superimpose{{=}{\cdot}}}}

\begin{document}

$\veewedge_{\veewedge}\lessgreater_{\lessgreater}\strikeQ_{\strikeQ}$

$A\dotineq B$ $\scriptstyle A\dotineq B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

With a different and perhaps more intuitive syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\superimpose}[3][\mathord]{#1{\mathpalette\superimpose@{{#2}{#3}}}}
\newcommand{\superimpose@}[2]{\superimpose@@{#1}#2}
\newcommand{\superimpose@@}[3]{%
  \ooalign{%
    \hfil$\m@th#1#2$\hfil\cr
    \hfil$\m@th#1#3$\hfil\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\veewedge}{\superimpose[\mathbin]{\vee}{\wedge}}
\newcommand{\lessgreater}{\superimpose[\mathrel]{<}{>}}
\newcommand{\strikeQ}{\superimpose{\textnormal{---}}{Q}}

\newcommand{\dotineq}{\superimpose[\mathrel]{=}{\cdot}}

\begin{document}

$\veewedge_{\veewedge}\lessgreater_{\lessgreater}\strikeQ_{\strikeQ}$

$A\dotineq B$ $\scriptstyle A\dotineq B$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does using `\newcommand` or `\newcommand*` make a difference here?

Comment: @Mankka You could indeed use `\newcommand*{\superimpose}[2]{...}` in order to have a check for no end of paragraph in the argument. But as the macro is used as an auxiliary for defining other macros, it's not really important. For parameterless macros, `*` or no `*` makes no essential difference.

Comment: I created a new symbol `\newcommand*{\at}{\mathpalette\superimpose{{\diamond}{|}}}` and I wanted slightly more space around it, so I tried `\newcommand*{\at}{\mskip 1mu\mathpalette\superimpose{{\diamond}{|}}\mskip 1mu}`. The latter does not align the symbols in (for example) `since \(x \at T_D\) is`. My random attempts did not solve this, so I would be grateful if you could suggest a solution.

Comment: @Mankka I think you want the symbol to be a relation symbol, so `\newcommand{\at}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\superimpose{{\diamond}{|}}}}` should do.

Comment: I tried that, and while it might feel the logical thing to do, it has too much space. `1mu` is just right. :)

Comment: @Mankka I disagree. Anyway, I see no misalignment with 1mu at either side.

Comment: It works nicely! But I do not understand how. What is the purpose of the braces when calling the "private" macros; and what is the third parameter (or rather, the first) taken by `\superimpose@@`, which seems to be called only with two by `\superimpose@`?