# Crossing out arrows

Tags: symbols

Is there a command/package that allows one to cross out arrows? I'm picturing something like an "X" over the `$\to$` symbol. I am aware of the `ulem` package, which I think allows you to cross out text with a horizontal line, but that doesn't seem to work as well over arrows.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most mathematical symbols allow negation via the `\not` prefix. For example, consider the look of

```
f(x)\not=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\not\to\mathcal{A}
```

[image: Using \not to negate mathematical symbols]

There is also [`centernot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/centernot) which looks similar to `\not=` in the above case, yet different (perhaps not-so-good) from `\not\to`.

Alternatively, Scott Pakin's [Comprehensive Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) has a vast amount of mathematical symbols and their associated fonts/package inclusions.

Comment: Hm, that's not exactly what I was looking for, but it seems like an easy & sufficient alternative. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the [cancel](http://ctan.org/pkg/cancel) package:

```
\usepackage{cancel}
...
\cancel{text}
```

You should also see the solutions on [How do you superimpose two symbols over each other?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21644/how-do-you-superimpose-two-symbols-over-each-other), and the solution to [Diagonal strikeout starting too low and ending too high](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20643/diagonal-strikeout-starting-too-low-and-ending-too-high).

Another option is something like `$\mathrlap{\to}\times$`. If you add `\usepackage{xcolor}` then `$\mathrlap{\to}{\textcolor{red}\times}$` might be a better option.

Comment: Hm, what package do you need to use the $\mathrlap$ tag? Is that part of "mathtools" (judging from the link you referenced)?

Comment: Yes, the [`mathtools` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) provides `\mathrlap`, `\mathclap` and `\mathllap`.

Answer (score 4):

Found via [detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html):

```
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\nrightarrow
```