# How to make squiggly arrow with head going the opposite way

Tags: symbols, arrows

I'd like to have an arrow symbol that's like `/rightsquigarrow`, but, instead of a normal arrow, the head goes in the opposite way.  So, rather than looking like --> (but squiggly), looks like --< (but squiggly).  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Why not looking like `<--` ? What would be the meaning of waht you're asking for?

Comment: I'm looking for a symbol to express incompatibility.  So, in the notation I'd like to have, "p --> q" would express that p implies q, whereas "p --< q" would express that p is incompatible with q.  "p <-- q" would, by contrast, express that q implies p.

Comment: I see.  In this case, why not `p-->¬q`?

Comment: That would express that p implies not-q. Though that's the case just in case p is incompatible with q, that's a result of the formal system I develop, and I need a bit of notation to express incompatibility in order to say, for instance, that p implies not-q just in case p is incompatible with q.

It's important for what  I'm doing that implication and incompatibility are treated as equally basic, and it'd be nice for the notation to reflect that.

Comment: A squiggle headed with a vertical line, rather than an arrow-head, would also probably work just as well.  I just need something to express incompatibility as a complement to /rightsquigarrow's expressing implication.

Comment: There's also [symbols - Crossing out arrows - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24681/crossing-out-arrows)

Comment: Actually [math mode - Strike out an arrow with a small oblique segment like with \nrightarrow - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469588/strike-out-an-arrow-with-a-small-oblique-segment-like-with-nrightarrow) is probably better (claimed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not so hard to construct such a symbol using TikZ.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\newcommand*{\rightsquigarrowrev}{%
    \mathrel{\raisebox{.5mm}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[-<, line cap=round, decorate, decoration={
                zigzag,
                segment length=3.7,
                amplitude=.8,
                post length=2pt
            }] (0,0) -- (.3,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }}%
}
\begin{document}
\(A \rightsquigarrow B\)

\(A \rightsquigarrowrev B\)
\end{document}
```