Adaptative vertical offset and scaling in mathmode
In the following code, the raise placement is bad because of the use of raisebox{.3ex}{...}. What are the best practices for obtaining a versatile placement that adapts to the size of the mathematical font? Same question for the scaling of the TikZ picture.
% Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621737/6880

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\newcommand{\mytikzrel}{
  \mathrel{%
    \raisebox{.3ex}{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[
          <->,
          line cap = round,
          decorate,
          decoration = {
            zigzag,
            segment length = 1.7,
            amplitude      = .8,
            pre length     = 2pt,
            post length    = 2pt
          }
        ] (0,0) -- (.3,0);
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
  }
}

\begin{document}

$A \mytikzrel B$ vs $\Sigma_{A \mytikzrel B}$

\end{document}


you can use a mathchoice to customise the .3ex raise but do you also want to make the tikzpicture itself have smaller size in subscripts?

The primitive \vcenter centers on the vertical axis. But a correctly drawn symbol should scale accordingly, so no ex or pt. One usually uses \mathchoice/\mathpalette.

@DavidCarlisle \mathchoiceis easy to use. But what is the best way for scaling also the TikZ picture?

well I was just asking if you wanted that as your question only asks to adjust the raise amount

tikzscale maybe, but depends a bit what you're doing.

@cfr What I would like to achieve is the possibility to define new math symbols by using TikZ drawing capabilities.
