# Symbol for intersect transversally

Tags: math-mode

I want to use type an intersection symbol with a vertical line to indicate intersect transversally of submanifolds, like this:

[image]

The symbol I looked up on detexify isn't quite what I want (it gives me `\usepackage{ amssymb }
$$\pitchfork$$`). Does anyone know how to get this symbol? Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with `amssymb`?

Comment: @Bernard -- The vertical member in the `amssymb` `\pitchfork` cuts off at the bottom of the cap.  The vertical line here has a distinct descender.  I don't know the difference in meaning, but it may be significant.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: when I compile, the vertical line starts nearly at the base line, without any descender w.r.t. the standard `\cap`.

Comment: There's a symbol `\mlcp` in the `stix` fonts.  Check the comprehensive symbols list (`texdoc comprehensive`).

Comment: I'm doing an applied math course and the lecturer is using a different symbol for "transversal intersection" ([like this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134863/command-for-transverse-and-not-pitchfork-as-used-in-guillemin-and-pollack)).  The symbol you show is actually [utf-8 character `0xU+2ADB`](https://www.utf8icons.com/character/10971/transversal-intersection): ⫛

Answer (score 3):

Combining other symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
N_1 \cap\kern-0.7em|\kern0.7em N_2
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]