# Importing only pitchfork symbol from mathabx package while working with amssymb package

Tags: amssymb, mathabx

I am using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134869/202532) to make transversality symbol. It gives[image: plain\transv] as I am using `amssymb`. But, if I use the package `mathabx` and slightly modify(`changed package,  \lineskip-.57ex`) the answer, it shows[image: mathbx\transv].
Now, there is a clash between `amssymb` and `mathabx`.

> I want to import this shape from `mathabx` for the latter symbol while
> working with the package `amssymb`. In other words, I want to use `mathabx` to produce the symbol[image: mathbx\transv] **only**, any other symbols as usual from `amssymb`.

Modified code for the symbol [image: mathbx\transv]:

```
\usepackage{amsmath,mathabx}

\newcommand{\transv}{\mathrel{\text{\tpitchfork}}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tpitchfork}{%
  \vbox{
    \baselineskip\z@skip
    \lineskip-.57ex
    \lineskiplimit\maxdimen
    \m@th
    \ialign{##\crcr\hidewidth\smash{$-$}\hidewidth\crcr$\pitchfork$\crcr}
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$$\Huge\transv $$


\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this help?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to use  the `mathabx \pitchfork`. I added an example of how to obtain something close to what you want  with the `\stackinset` command from `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{%
  <-6> mathb5
  <6-7> mathb6
  <7-8> mathb7
  <8-9> mathb8
  <9-10> mathb9
  <10-12> mathb10
  <12-> mathb12
  } {}%
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\abxpitchfork}{\mathord}{mathb}{"26}

\usepackage{stackengine} 

\begin{document}

\[ X \abxpitchfork Y\]%
\[ X \stackinset{c}{}{c}{0.1ex}{$\top$}{$\abxpitchfork$} Y\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]