# Custom Shape on the Integral Sign

Tags: math-mode, integral

So, I want to have an integral sign with a square or a triangle in the middle. Is there a way for me to put a custom shape (supported by latex) on the integral sign? I know that there is `\oint`, but I want other shapes. Any ideas?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243478/ or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284899.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Does [this posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220209/5001) help? (To get a composite symbol, with a `\square` instead of a `\sim`symbol overlapping the integral symbol, all you'd need to do is (a) load the `amssymb` package and (b) add `\def\sqint{\Yint\square}` and `\def\trint{\Yint\triangle}` in the preamble.)