# What are the LaTeX codes for clockwise and counter-clockwise integrals (∱ and ⨑)?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, integral

If you do know, which package do I need to use? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With the `MnSymbol` package, you could use the following symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}

\[
\rcirclerightint
\lcirclerightint
\rcircleleftint
\lcircleleftint
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

(other package might know these symbols as `\ointclockwise` and `\ointctrclockwise`)

---

If you only want half a circle, you can use the `mathdesign` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}

\[
\intclockwise
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if you search unicode 0x2231, you will see that there is only half a circle drawn. I need that one.

Comment: @trckojr If you want a particular shape of a symbol, it would be best if you would include an image of the symbol in your question and don't trust that search machines will return the same result you see for all people

Comment: The second answer from you solved my problem. Thank you very much. I will make sure to include an image next time I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 13):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{array,esint}
\def\CMD#1{%
   $ \csname#1\endcsname \displaystyle\csname#1\endcsname $ & \texttt{\textbackslash#1} &}

\begin{document}
\def\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{2}{r@{\kern3pt}l}r@{\kern3pt}l@{}l@{}}
\CMD{int}   \CMD{iint}     \CMD{iiintop} \\
\CMD{iiiintop}\CMD{dotsintop}\CMD{ointop}  \\
\CMD{oiint}   \CMD{sqint}    \CMD{sqiint} \\
\CMD{ointctrclockwise} \CMD{ointclockwise} \CMD{varointclockwise} \\
\CMD{varointctrclockwise} \CMD{fint} \CMD{varoiint}\\
\CMD{landupint} \CMD{landdownint}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Although some of the symbols in `esint` come very close, I don't believe there is any package (for pdfLaTeX) that provides a version of this symbol compatible with the computer modern maths font.

The following is a (very simple) adaption of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171445) by Heiko Oberdiek.
It can be used to superimpose any symbol on top of an integral sign.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} %% <- for \resizebox and \rotatebox
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} %% <- for \curverightarrow, \curveleftarrow

\makeatletter %% <- make @ usable in macro names

\let\DOTSI\relax % amsmath support for \dots
\newcommand*{\letteronint}[1]{%
  \DOTSI
  \mathop{%
    \mathpalette\@LetterOnInt{#1}%
  }%
  \mkern-\thinmuskip % thin space is inserted between two \mathop
  \int
}
\newcommand*{\@LetterOnInt}[2]{%
  \sbox0{$#1\int\m@th$}%
  \sbox2{$%
    \ifx#1\displaystyle
      \textstyle
    \else
      \scriptscriptstyle
    \fi
    #2%
  \m@th$}%
  \dimen@=.4\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax
  \ifdim\dimexpr\ht2+\dp2\relax>\dimen@
    \sbox2{\resizebox*{!}{\dimen@}{\unhcopy2}}%
  \fi
  \dimen@=\wd0 %
  \ifdim\wd2>\dimen@
    \dimen@=\wd2 %
  \fi
  \rlap{\hbox to \dimen@{\hfil
    $#1\vcenter{\copy2}\m@th$%
  \hfil}}%
  \ifdim\dimen@>\wd0 %
    \kern.5\dimexpr\dimen@-\wd0\relax
  \fi
}

%% Define arrow curving downwards:
\newcommand*{\curvearrowbotright}{\mathpalette\rotmath@internal\curvearrowleft}
\newcommand*\rotmath@internal[2]{\rotatebox{180}{$\m@th#1#2$}}

\makeatother %% <- revert @

\newcommand*{\intcw}{\letteronint{\mspace{3mu}\curvearrowright}}
\newcommand*{\intccw}{\letteronint{\mspace{3mu}\curvearrowbotright}}


\begin{document}

\[
  \displaystyle      \intcw_a^b f \dots \intccw_a^b f \qquad
  \textstyle         \intcw_a^b f \dots \intccw_a^b f \qquad
  \scriptstyle       \intcw_a^b f \dots \intccw_a^b f \qquad
  \scriptscriptstyle \intcw_a^b f \dots \intccw_a^b f
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The `\scriptscriptstyle` version does not look good, but you probably won't want to use this symbol at that scale.

Comment: Very nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\( \intclockwise \awint \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Clockwise and counterclockwise integrals]

The symbols are also in a number of legacy NFSS packages, including: `fdsymbol`, `newpxmath`, `newtxmath`, `pxfonts`, `txfonts`, `stix` and `stix2`. Some also support other aliases, but all have been updated to understand `\intclockwise` and `\awint`.

Some of these also include variants, such as `\intclockwiseup` and `\smallintclockwise` in `stix`. These are available in `unicode-math` as stylistic variants in some math fonts.

See [“The Comptehensive LaTeX Symbol List”](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) and [“Every symbol (most symbols) defined by
unicode-math.”](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf)