# Vertical line superimposed over a letter

Tags: symbols

Looking for a way to put a vertical line over another character.  Similar to the \cancel feature, but with a vertical, rather than a slanted line.  For example on a capital S the vertical line would turn it into something akin to a US dollar symbol: $. (verticallity in this text box seems dependent upon font choice)
i.e. superimpose a | over a C

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21647/15925 provides a general solution to this

Comment: While you could use `\newcommand{\vertchar}[1]{\ooalign{#1\cr\hidewidth$|$\hidewidth}}` with `\vertchar{s}` and `\vertchar{c}` (say), it doesn't really look nice with `\vertchar{S}` and `\vertchar{C}`. Could you be specific in terms of your actual usage?

Comment: Usage is in a review article I'm typing for a prof.  The hand written symbol looks like the two vert/C's in Oberdiek's example below.  I was able to make the \mathclap command work, actually coupled with a \mathcal to achieve an agreeable symbol.  This does tend to crowd a preceding (, but adding \hspace*(.01in) spaced things nicely.  I'm going to experiment with the others shown here.  Thanks Swann.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

The following solution uses TikZ (more configuration options as rounded line caps, ...). The optional argument of `\vertchar` allows horizontal fine tuning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand*{\vertchar}[2][0pt]{%
  \tikz[
    inner sep=0pt,
    shorten >=-.15ex,
    shorten <=-.15ex,
    line cap=round,
    baseline=(c.base),
  ]\draw
    (0,0) node (c) {#2}
    ($(c.south)+(#1,0)$) -- ($(c.north)+(#1,0)$);%
}
\begin{document}
  \vertchar{S} and \vertchar{C} or \vertchar[.08ex]{C}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

`\stackinset` allows you do do this with the syntax

`\stackinset{H-anchor}{H-offset}{V-anchor}{V-offset}{inset}{base}`

The inset and base can be glyphs, phrases, images, anything that can be set into a LaTeX box.  The H-anchors are l, c, or r.  The V-anchors are t, c, or b.  You can stack math by default by issuing `\stackMath`, which is done for the 2nd example of the MWE, where I simulate an `@` symbol by insetting a math `a` inside a math `O`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\rule{.4pt}{2ex}}{C}
\stackMath
\stackinset{c}{}{b}{1pt}{a}{O}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The insets can be nested to inset multiple things over one base, such as in this answer: [Mathematical formulas on a graph (not made by TeX)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171483/mathematical-formulas-on-a-graph-not-made-by-tex/171486#171486)