# code for arrow with a short vertical line in the middle of the shaft

Tags: arrows

I'm trying to produce an arrow similar to $\nrightarrow $ only with the smaller line being vertical rather than horizontal. I went over the big list of latex symbols several times and could not find it. Any help would be appreciated (I'm using xypic, so extended codes are fine if xypic supports them).

Comment: This might be helpful: 
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21644/how-do-you-superimpose-two-symbols-over-each-other
It essentially describes how you can draw two symbol on top of each other.

Comment: this symbol is in unicode at U+21F8, so it is in the stix and xits fonts with the name `\nvrightarrow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following?

[image]

To fine-tune the position of the vertical bar along the shaft of the arrow, either decrease or increase the arguments of both `\mkern` directives by the same amounts; just make sure that the arguments sum to `-9mu`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\tobar{\mathrel{\mkern3mu  \vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle+$}}%
                    \mkern-12mu{\to}}}
\begin{document}
$a\tobar z$

$a\to z$
\end{document}
```

Comment: very neat, except that the vertical bar is somewhat thinner than the arrow shaft.  at normal size, this might fade away in photocopying.