# My markings are not working (pgfkeys : key '/tikz/marking' unkown)

Tags: arrows, tikz-cd, pgfkeys

So I am trying to draw barred arrow in tikzcd, and following the answer of for example here :https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493140/236919 . It does not work because of marking.
The other (much more complicated) solutions work for my problem

The minimal code is :

```
\documentclass{article}
\listfiles
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[]
    a \arrow[r,"|" marking] & b
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

The expected result is :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISB5L.png

Using pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18, I have the following warning :

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/marking' and I
> am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
>
> See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>   for immediate help ... l.5 I think the culprit is a tikzcd
> arrow in cell 1-1. \errmessage ...currentrow -\tikzcd@currentcolumn }
> l.6 \end{tikzcd}
> ]
>
> ? H This error message was generated by an \errmessage command, so I can't give any explicit help. Pretend that
> you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues, and deduce the truth by
> order and method.
>
> ?

and the pdf produced is as follows:
[image]

the arrow is drawn, but the marking is ignored, thus the bar "|" is treated as a label and drawn above.

Could there be an issue with my pgfkeys package? I don't remember manually installing it, or how I installed latex/pdftex/..., but for what it's worth, I installed latex along TeXstudio 2.12.6 (hg 6631:16db084dae24)

Edit : after adding \listfiles to have the versions of my packages, here is a pastebin of the full log file :

https://pastebin.com/66d4q7pe

I am not sure what to look for, but here is the result of
$ grep Package: barred_arrow.log
(plus some line breaks) :

> Package: tikz-cd 2014/10/30 v0.9e Commutative diagrams with tikz
>
> Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
>
> Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
>
> Package: pgf 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
>
> Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
>
> Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
>
> Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
>
> Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
>
> Package: pgfsys 2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
>
> Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
>
> Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
>
> Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
>
> Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
>
> Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
>
> Package: tikz 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
>
> Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
>
> Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error
> messages (HO)
>
> Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
>
> Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
>
> Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general
> use (HO)
>
> Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package
> options (HO)
>
> Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
>
> Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX
> commands (HO)
>
> Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
>
> Package: pdftexcmds 2018/01/21 v0.26 Utility functions of pdfTeX for
> LuaTeX (HO
>
> Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch

Comment: Your code works as expected in my setup (current TeXLive 2022). So you should state the versions of your packages... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13304/which-package-version-am-i-using

Comment: You have a *very* old installation. Mine says `pgfsys.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)`   `tikz-cd.sty 2021/05/04 v1.0 Commutative diagrams with TikZ` etc... so probably simply your version has no `marking` option. You need to upgrade your LaTeX system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works perfectly with a recent version of TeX Live (since 2018 on).

In case you can't update your distribution, you can adjust the position of the `|` with other options: `shift`, `yshift`, `xshift`, `rotate`, as appropriate.

For example, here I've used `yshift`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    a \arrow[r,"|" yshift={-6pt}] & b
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]