# Incidence Symbol for Geometry

Tags: symbols

My professor invented a symbol for when a line and a point are geometrically incident. I added a picture and wanted to ask if someone knows how to write this in LaTex?
It is a small line with a dot in the middle.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\incid}{%
\tikz{%
    \draw[line cap=round,line width=0.13ex] (0,0)--(3ex,0);
    \fill (1.5ex,0) circle (0.5ex);
}}

\begin{document}
$(P, G, \incid)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. Is there an easy way to make the gaps between any input and the symbol a little wider on both sides?

Comment: No need for an answer, I figured to add \hspace in the command.

Answer (score 13):

This should be a relation symbol. It can be obtained with the sequence

```
\relbar \joinrel \mathrel{\!\bullet\!} \joinrel \relbar
```

The `\relbar` command typesets a minus sign considered as a relation symbol; `\joinrel` is a small negative space considered as a relation symbol. The `\bullet` is made into a relation symbol, with reduced sidebearings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\incidence}{\relbar\joinrel\mathrel{\!\bullet\!}\joinrel\relbar}

\begin{document}

$(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{G},\incidence)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Here's another solution that uses the method [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21647/411) for superimposing symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\superimpose}[2]{%
  {\ooalign{$#1\@firstoftwo#2$\cr\hfil$#1\@secondoftwo#2$\hfil\cr}}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\incidentsymb}{%
    \mathpalette\superimpose{%
        {\rule[0.5ex]{1.2em}{0.5pt}}%
        {\text{\textbullet}}%
    }%
}


\begin{document}

$(\mathcal{P}, \mathcal{G}, \incidentsymb)$

\end{document}
```

[image: incidence symbol]

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to do this is:

```tex
{-}\!{\bullet}\!{-}
```

Curly braces are used to suppress natural spaces; `\!` is a negative space.

[image]

Of course, you can use `\newcommand`:

```tex
\newcommand{\incid}{{-}\!{\bullet}\!{-}}
```

A bit thicker line:

```tex
{\bf-}\!\!{\bullet}\!\!{\bf-}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but, please,  note that `\bf` has been deprecated for about 30 years. In the particular case it does exactly nothing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, one way that  works only with `luatatex`. With `xelatex`  work adding `\ensuremath` before `\bullet`, but with `pdflatex` also failed miserably.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\newcommand\incidence{\mathrel{\rotatebox{90}{\bullet\kern-.4em|}}}
\begin{document}
$(\mathcal{P}, \mathcal{G}, \incidence )$
\end{document}
```